# Raster to PNG Coding Discrepancy

Tags: html, image, svg, png, raster

My question is concerning the pause Raster to PNG

I converted the play raster to png, and that went through smoothly without an issue.

I do the pause one next and they both don't look the same.

How do I fix that? And can it be fixed?

Can something be adjusted in the code to fix/address the issue?

https://jsfiddle.net/m1vs3gp7/

[image]

```
<div style="
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;

      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/DP1EiiG.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 14px 18px;
        background-position: 50%;
        border-radius: 500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        cursor: pointer;
    "> </div>
```

[image]

```
<div style="
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;

      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 14px 18px;
        background-position: 50%;
        border-radius: 500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        cursor: pointer;
    "> </div>
```

[image]

```
<div style="
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;

      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/ef35w1e.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 14px 18px;
        background-position: 58% 50%;
        border-radius: 500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        cursor: pointer;
    "> </div>
```

[image]

```
<div style="
        width: 36px;
        height: 36px;

      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTIyNiAxNDgxIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDEzOTRWODdDMCA0Ni4zIDEzLjMgMTkuOCA0MCA3LjUgNjYuNy00LjggOTguNy4zIDEzNiAyM2wxMDM0IDYzNGMzNy4zIDIyLjcgNTYgNTAuMyA1NiA4M3MtMTguNyA2MC4zLTU2IDgzTDEzNiAxNDU4Yy0zNy4zIDIyLjctNjkuMyAyNy44LTk2IDE1LjUtMjYuNy0xMi4zLTQwLTM4LjgtNDAtNzkuNXoiIGZpbGw9IiNmZmYiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: 14px 18px;
        background-position: 58% 50%;
        border-radius: 500px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        cursor: pointer;
    "> </div>
```

Comment: Add `width` and `height` attributes on your `<svg>` node.

Comment: What do you mean? All of them have width/height.

Comment: Your svg documents don't have their `width` and `height` attributes set, set it. Otherwise, whatever tool you are using to do the rasterization will only guess what their size is, since the default is `100%`. Once decoded, your opening `<svg>` tag for the *pause* image is `<svg viewBox="0 0 1260 1512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">` There is no `width` nor `height` in here.

Comment: How came I didn't need to do that with the Play raster to PNG?

Comment: Because you got lucky?

Comment: I thought doing this would address that. background-size: 14px 18px;

Comment: Thank you, doing what you said worked. https://jsfiddle.net/m7oym0x9/

Comment: That's weird cause adding background-size: 14px 18px; fixed the play raster to png by itself, that's all I needed to do.

Comment: How does Spotify do it without adding width or height? https://jsfiddle.net/4dga48o7/1/ Is there anything in the code they use that tells you that?